# Can anyone explain this thrust - weight - lift paradox for airplanes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, aircraft, lift

Engineers are confronted with two apparently true but contradictory statements:

a)  Lift must equal the weight of the airplane (Lift = Weight), based on Newtons 2nd Law of motion (i.e. Force = ma); where gravity is used to calculate weight (i.e. Weight = mass x gravity).

b)  Commercial airliners such as Boeing 747-400 and Airbus 320 have thrust-to-weight ratios of about 0.3.

These two equations are combined to provide equation (c), as follows: If ‘Lift = Weight’ (a) was true; then airliners’ that fly with thrust-to-WEIGHT ratios of 0.3 (b); logically must also fly with thrust-to-LIFT ratios of 0.3 (c); This is summarised by the equations:

(a)   Lift  =  Weight

(b)   Thrust / Weight  =   0.3

(c)   Thrust  / Lift       =   0.3

For example, Boeing 747-400 (B-747) specifications:

- A maximum mass of 396,890 kg provides a weight of 3,890 kN
  (i.e.  3,890 kN  =  396,890 kg  x  9.8 m/s2).
- Four Pratt & Whitney PW4062 engines each with a thrust of 281.6 kN provide a maximum total engine thrust of 1,126 kN
  (i.e.  1,126 kN  =  4  x  281.6 kN).
- Aircraft thrust-to-weight ratio of 0.3
  (i.e. 0.3 = 1,126 kN / 3,890 kN).

[image]

Image: B-747,  Thrust / Weight  =  0.3

But there is a problem. Applying these equations to the B-747 produces a result that is implausible.  See image attached.

- It should be impossible for the B-747 to fly, as the lift required exceeds engine thrust by a wide margin of 2,764 kN. The B-747  would not even be able to take-off with engine thrust of only 30% of the lift required to fly. Yet the B-747 flies in practice.
- There is no plausible explanation how a B-747’s wings can produce lift 245%, or 2,764 kN, in excess of thrust. Lift cannot be created from nothing, and the engines are the only mechanism pushing the airplane forwards and up. Therefore, engine thrust must be greater than lift (i.e. Thrust > Lift).  Not vice versa. Observations from airplanes in flight confirm this assertion. The backwash from engine thrust far exceeds the downwash from wings created due to lift by a wide margin.

This analysis means that equation (c) ‘Thrust / Lift = 0.3’ is false.

Hence a paradox arises, as both equations (a) and (b) appear to be true when stated individually, but when combined produce a result, equation (c), that is false (i.e. impossible).

[image]

Therefore, one of the equations (a) and (b) is also false, but which one?

(a)   Lift  =  Weight

(b)   Thrust / Weight  =   0.3

Sources for data: www.modernairliners.com; Boeing [www.boeing.com](http://www.boeing.com)

https://modernairliners.com/boeing-747-jumbo/boeing-747-specs/

Comment: For us to be able to answer this question, you need to give us more context. You say that the amount of lift is "extremely unlikely" -- but why do you think that? You ask for experimental proof -- so why isn't the very fact that these plane work not experimental proof?

Comment: Gliders have 0 thrust, but still have lift.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103183/discussion-on-question-by-nick-landell-how-can-lift-weight-if-airliners-fly-w).

Comment: This question is essentially just asking if Newton's laws are true.

Comment: "The lift generated by the wings is not observed to be 3.3x greater than the thrust produced by the en engines of an airliner."  Where are you getting this information?  I'm pretty sure this is _exactly_ what aircraft designers find to be the case.  They get the ratio based on what is realistically going to happen; they don't just make them up.

Comment: Do you mean that it's impossible for aircraft manufacturers like Boeing to make a mistake designing an airplane?

Comment: For example, casual observation that an airliner's wings are not producing 3.3x the thrust from the engines includes: Standing behind an airliner's engines (at a safe distance) of 50 meters, the backwash from the engines is noticeable. But the downwash under the wings of the same airplane is not noticeable at a distance of 50 meters below the wings (say when the airplane is taking off).  The downwash is not even noticeable at 20 meters below the wings.

Comment: @NickLandell There's a park near me which is sometimes right under the flight path to & from a large airport. When a plane goes by, it doesn't take long for the trailing vortices (propelled downward by the wing's downwash) to reach the ground and shake the trees & bushes violently. So, I would disagree about the downwash not being noticeable (& at a much larger distance than 20 meters).

Answer (score 5):

The thrust is used to keep the plane at a constant speed $v$ in horizontal direction. It compensates the friction, which would slow the plane down. However, the lift is due to Bernoulli's equation
$p + \frac{\rho}{2}v^2 + \rho g h = const$
which for constant height becomes $p + \frac{\rho}{2}v^2 = const$. Thus the thrust is given by $$F = A \cdot \Delta p = A \cdot \frac{\rho}{2} [v_{below}^2 - v_{above}^2]$$ where $A$ is the area of the wings, $\rho$ is the mass density of the air at height $h$, and the two velocities are the wind speeds above and below the wings -- since the pressure difference is not constant along the wing, we would obtain an integral, if we would do the calculation properly.

From this simple equation we see, that the thrust is proportional to the area of the wings. If the friction was arbitrary small, the thrust/weight ratio could become arbitrary large, by increasing the area of the wings.

Comment: Good answer, backed up by lift/drag wind tunnel studies.  A flat plate indeed has a lift maximum at 45 degrees deflection, but with huge drag.  Same lift at around 15 degrees deflection (much less drag) is obtained by Bernoulli as described so well here.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni What force is your F? Lift, or thrust?

Comment: This is false. There's not one scientific experiment on a real airplane that proves what you say to be true. NASA says it false, many academics say its false ......

Comment: @NickLandell go to the playground and try the see-saw with one 3.3 times heavier than you.  How do you explain this "magic"?

Comment: Sure, but to state the obvious problem with the leverage argument: An airplane wing has no fulcrum, so no leverage is possible. Worse, an airplane is moving not static, so the playground analogy fails.

Answer (score 3):

That's FULL thrust, used when taking off (climbing the hill, so to speak). It is much larger than drag. Typical drag in a jet transport is more like 4% of weight, not 30%.

Comment: This is probably better suited as a comment on the question, though it is a good point.

Comment: What do you want to say?